# What css code is controling the button hover color?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the buttons at the top right side of the web site have a different hover color than grey. I was shooting for a lighter orange. Here are the btn css codes I have used.

```
button.btn.btn-mini, input[type="submit"].btn.btn-mini {
  background-color: #F47825;
  color: white;
}

button.btn.add-wishlist.bapi-wishlisttracker {
  background-color: #F47825;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #F47825;
}
.btn {
   background-color: #f45F25;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f47825, #f45F25);
   border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) #f47825;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(208, 76, 43);
   color: #ffffff;
 }
.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #F47825;
    background-position: 0 -30px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-position .1s linear;
    -o-transition: background-position .1s linear;
    transition: background-position .1s linear;
}
.btn:active, .btn.active {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #D04C2B;
}
```

This can be seen at http://www.clearwaterfloridabeachrentals.com/rentals/rentalsearch/

Comment: The one with `:hover` maybe...?

Comment: Where exactly on this website are you trying to change the button hover color?

Comment: At top right there are three orange buttons that say List | Photo | Map.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your're wanting to change:

```
.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
    background-color: #F47825;
}
```

or possibly this

```
.btn-primary:hover {
background-color: #F47825;
}
```

any .class_name:hover controls the what happens when you place the mouse over.

Comment: That hex code written in the code is the orange color I want. Even with the code written as you put it above the hover is gray not the orange that is coded. Something must be over riding it.

Comment: The classes on that button are .btn, . changeview, .active . so i'd try .btn:hover, .changeview:hover, .active:hover {background-color:#F47825}

If that fails add in a <style> tag after all your style sheets if you think somethings overwriting it.